# SSIS - Converting DT_TEXT(Length 11,000 Characters) to DT_STR and trim to 1,000 characters

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012, type-conversion

I want to read data from text file (.csv), truncate one of the column to 1000 characters and push into SQL table using SSIS Package.

The input (DT_TEXT) is of length 11,000 characters but my Challenge is ...

- SSIS can convert to (DT_STR) only if Max length is 8,000 characters.
- String operations cannot be performed on Stream (DT_TEXT data type)

Comment: Have you tried performing the conversion in a script transformation?

Comment: No... If I am not able to find a solution with regular conversions and transformations, I will work on Script Task.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Got a workaround/solution now;
I truncate the text in Flat File Source and selected the option to Ignore the Error;

Please share if you find a better solution!

FYI:
[image: Truncating8000PlusCharsInSSIS]

Comment: After I do step 6, it reverts to the original - Unicode string [DT_WSTR] and size 255. Please help

Answer (score 4):

To help anyone else that finds this, I applied a similar concept more generally in a data flow when consuming a text stream [DT_TEXT] in a Derived Column Transformation task to transform it to [DT_WSTR] type to my defined length.  This more easily calls out the conversion taking place.

Expression: (DT_WSTR,1000)(DT_STR,1000,1252)myLargeTextColumn 

Data Type: Unicode string [DT_WSTR]

Length: 1000

*I used 1252 codepage since my DT_TEXT is UTF-8 encoded.

For this Derived Column, I also set the TruncationRowDisposition to RD_IgnmoreFailure in the Advanced Editor (or can be done in the Configure Error Output, setting Truncation to "Ignore failure")

*(I'd post images but apparently I need to boost my rep)*