# How to open Advanced Editor for Flat File import in SSMS?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

Importing a CSV - I get a truncation error

> Error 0xc020902a: Data Flow Task 1: The "Source - Train_csv.Outputs[Flat File Source Output].Columns["Title"]" failed because truncation occurred, and the truncation row disposition on "Source - Train_csv.Outputs[Flat File Source Output].Columns["Title"]" specifies failure on truncation. A truncation error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.

I used a method from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18600571/16364945) and sadly got another error. So I have tried using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28628046/16364945).

**Problem that I encounter**
I am unable to open the advanced editor. I cannot see this button anywhere.

What I've tried to solve it

- googling
- youtube
- stackoverflow
- help in SSMS,
- opening the import tool from start menu and going to advanced tab.

I'm running out of ideas here. Specifically, I don't know what to click in order to find the menu from no 2 on the picture below:

[image]

**Edit:
This error is copy pasted from the ANSWER 1, as it's basically the same what I get, just different columns there.

Also, answering Brad's question:
[A view from my SSMS after right click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H48VP.png)
**

Edit2: **Possibly solved**

AlwaysLearning said in the comments that this menu is not present in SSMS but in SSIS. I have been trying to google where to get it but I seem to be to tired to deal with it for now, therefore I will wait for others to confirm it or go back to it tomorrow. After I've found it in SSIS, I will make an edit here. T

Comment: Is it maybe column [Title] first or last column?

Comment: I thought you right clicked on the task and there is option for advanced editor.

Comment: I think I can see the source of your confusion. The screen shots in your question, and from the second answer link, are not from SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio), they're from the package editor in SSIS (SQL Server Integration Services).

Answer (score 0):

**Solved **

Just as AlwaysLearning said in the comments (sorry, I cannot click 'useful' yet as I'm new here), this menu is in SSIS, not SSMS. I struggled a lot to find it, so here's how to do that:

1. In [This YT video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rRfOrvY0qgc) it is explained how to install SSIS through Visual Studio.
2. In [This YT video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aMhwCepVpwE) it's explained how to find this menu box in SSIS

Thanks for help guys